# Scroll down after form submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form (searchbar) with a submit button.
After that I want the page to smoothly scroll down to the next section.
I cant seem to find a good working snippet though.

I have tried to do it with Jquery .animate, but it won't work cause the page refreshes. I have tried to put the section to scroll to in the form action too, but that is instant, not smooth.

Some solutions?

```js
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#twee").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
  <form action="index.php#twee" method="post">
        <div class="searchbar">
     <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Zoek een game">
        </div>
        <div class="submitButton">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
        </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Bedoel je nadat iemand iets zoekt, wil je dat de pagina naar beneden scrollt?

Comment: Ja precies. Zodra iemand op submit drukt wordt de zoekterm in een variabele opgeslagen en op basis van die variabele worden dingen uit de database gehaald. Hij moet dus wel refreshen, anders kan die de nieuwe gegevens niet laten zien, maar omdat die dus refreshed werkt .animate niet.

Comment: Heb je mischien een voorbeeld, wat die nu doet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code in index.php page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var href = window.location.href; 
    var splitit = (href.split('#'))[1]; //split url to get twee name
    if(splitit !== "" || splitit !== "undefined"){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+splitit).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

and remove animate from your form submit event

Comment: @JordySenssen  add this code in <script> tag after jquery  and then call index.php#twee directly in your browser and see what you get